# In Perforce, list all changesets by user

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, how do I list all changesets for a given user?
Can that be done via a single "p4" command?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

```
p4 changes -u <username>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Powershell 2.0:

```
p4 users 
    | select-string "^\w+(.\w+)?" | %{$_.Matches} | %{$_.Value} 
    | %{p4 changes -u $_}
```

The first line shows all users, the second line parses out the username from the output, adn the third line sends that input to `p4 changes`.

EDIT: The regex assumes your usernames are either a single word or a firstname.lastname format.  You may need to edit it for different formats.

EDIT2: Ooooh for a *given* user.  Arse.

EDIT3: Shorter powershell:

```
p4 users 
    | select-string "^\w+(.\w+)?" | %{$_.Matches} 
    | %{p4 changes -u $_.Value }
```

EDIT4: even shorter powershell:

```
p4 users | % { p4 changes -u $_.Split()[0] }
```

Answer (score 1):

For details of the changes for each changelist use:

```
p4 changes -u <user_name> | %{p4 describe $_.Split()[1]}
```

Use `-s` option for describe if you don't need the file diff.

Answer (score 0):

p4 changes -m 1 -L -t -u

Answer (score 0):

```
p4 -u <username>
```

Tried on "Rev. P4V/NTX64/2019.1/1797168"